# Rails: Stripe webhooks for `invoice.payment_action_required` & `invoice.payment_failed`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I am sending customer emails when i get the events `invoice.payment_action_required` & `invoice.payment_failed`.

this causes a email to be sent to the user when they are subscribing for the first time and are `on_session`.

How do i ensure that the emails are not getting sent the user is subscribing the first time but are only sent when the events happen for recurring payments.

Any help on this would be really great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the `billing_reason` of the Invoice in the Event so you can identify and ignore events relating to to the first payment of a subscription(they'd have `subscription_create`).

https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason

Answer (score 0):

Checking the `billing_reason` is not equal to `subscription_create` will prevent some of the emails when the user is entering card details. However there are other scenarios.

For example, when a recurring payment fails and the customer visits the customer portal to add a payment method, the `billing_reason` will now be `subscription_cycle` should either of the webhooks trigger.

I'd love to know if there's a way to tell from the webhook payload (invoice object) if the user is present. Failing this, I see the only option is not to send an email immediately, but wait for a configured amount of time, before checking the invoice to see if it is still in an open state, and then deciding whether to send the relevant email.